# AzureML: Engine process terminated. This is most likely due to system running out of memory. Please retry with increased memory

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am trying to run an experiment on AzureML through the notebook. I get the above error on trying to read a dataset created in previous step.

I checked the memory usage through command - `df -h` and it looks ok. I checked git links with same error, but that doesn't appear to have been resolved.

Github issues [link](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1143)

What is going wrong here?

Below line of code gives the error. This line had run successfully just a day ago on same workspace, using same compute.

[image]

Below is the screen of memory:

[image]

Comment: I am having the same error. And the code block getting the error was working fine 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

our team is working on a fix, sorry about the inconvenience.

Until then you have two possible work-around:
You can switch to Jupyter notebook instead of using integrated notebook or you can add below snippet to your notebook:

```
import oscurrent_dir = os.getcwd()
if not current_dir.endswith('/code'):
  os.chdir(current_dir+'/code')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Have been using a AML notebook with 7 GB RAM to train a timeseries model on 5 MB of data. Training would complete in 2 seconds. Been doing this every other day for months and now I am getting `MemoryError: Engine process terminated. This is most likely due to system running out of memory. Please retry with increased memory.` Strange that we get the error after about 1 second, which is not what you would expect with a MemoryError. This even after I upgrade to 28 GB RAM. Something must have changed on AML side? But there is nothing in the release notes.

Comment: Was getting the error even with `Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'dataset-name')`, but the error disappeared and all is working fine again now. Have started rather using the Jupyter notebook instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue this morning - exact same error message as in Charl's answer, just when calling `Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'dataset-name')` from a notebook.

Then this error seemed to resolve itself, with no changes on my end, but now many other cells in the notebook that would make very little memory demand (e.g. instantiating `OutputDatasetConfig(...)`, or trying to do anything at all with the dataset) are throwing the same error.